# Inheritance, polymorphisms and class PYTHON 3

Tags: python-3.x

Can anybody help me make the first step of the program as an example to do.
The task is to make personal notebook in where you could do: make or look for adresses, type an information, mark your jobs and do a calendar to look what date you have a job listed. it doesnt need to save any text.

I was think of making a menu, but then coudnt get further after it because didnt know how to work with inheritance and polymorphism trough it.[Thats is what i  made already](https://i.stack.imgur.com/M05fZ.png)

But the function doesnt get trough after the def ivest(self):

Anybody can help?

Comment: What do you mean by "But the function doesnt get trough"? What are you expecting the program to do and how does the actual behaviour differ from your expectations?

Comment: The def ivest(self) just doesnt work well and because of that it just doesnt work. I want to know if its even possible to output the text and check it if it will be there with the code i wrote